# Customer success messages disappear too fast in magento 2

Tags: frontend, customer-account, magento2.4.1, success-message, customer-registration

Once the customer completed the registration, the success message hide too fast?

Kindly guide me to any solution to sort it out?

Answer (score 0):

You need to increase timeout period on messages.js file

```
vendor/magento/module-ui/view/frontend/web/js/view/messages.js
```

You should override that js file or use mixin in your module and set the time out  milliseconds.

```
onHiddenChange: function (isHidden) {
            // Hide message block if needed
            if (isHidden) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(this.selector).hide('blind', {}, this.hideSpeed);
                }.bind(this), this.hideTimeout);
            }
        }
```

update ohHiddenChnage hideTimeout value like.

```
onHiddenChange: function (isHidden) {
            // Hide message block if needed
            if (isHidden) {
                setTimeout(function () {
                    $(this.selector).hide('blind', {}, this.hideSpeed);
                }.bind(this), 30000);
            }
        }}
            }
```

You can get more details from

[Increase display time of exception message in magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/182313/increase-display-time-of-exception-message-in-magento-2)